# Does Laravel query database each time I call Auth::user()?

Tags: authentication, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

In my Laravel application I used `Auth::user()` in multiple places. I am just worried that Laravel might be doing some queries on each call of `Auth::user()`

Kindly advice

Comment: model won't cache automatically.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No the user model is cached. Let's take a look at `Illuminate\Auth\Guard@user`:

```
public function user()
{
    if ($this->loggedOut) return;

    // If we have already retrieved the user for the current request we can just
    // return it back immediately. We do not want to pull the user data every
    // request into the method because that would tremendously slow an app.
    if ( ! is_null($this->user))
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
```

As the comment says, after retrieving the user for the first time, it will be stored in `$this->user` and just returned back on the second call.

Comment: Please note that this is not persistent between different requests. What I mean is that each time there is a new request (e.g: User refreshes the page), regardless of the inner caching, the driver goes to database every time.

Answer (score 5):

For same Request, If you run `Auth::user()` multiple time, it will only run 1 `query` and not multiple time.
But , if you go and call for another request with `Auth::user()` , it will go and run 1 `query` again.

This cannot be cached for all request after first request has been made due to security point of view.

So, It runs 1 query per request irrespective of number of time you are calling.

I see use of some session here to avoid run multiple query, so you can try these code : http://laravel.usercv.com/post/16/using-session-against-authuser-in-laravel-4-and-5-cache-authuser

Thanks

Comment: Caching between requests will be important when the user is not in a local database, but at the end of an API that may take some time to fetch.