# Does Laravel reuse models?

Tags: laravel

If I retrieve a model/collection in a controller and have the same call in a following event, will Laravel reuse the model/collection from the controller or fetch the data with a second database call?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I refer to a call like this:

```
User::where('user_id', 42)->first();
```

Comment: Depends on what call. If you can specify the exact function you intend to use, you can expect a concrete answer

Comment: Thanks, I added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `$user = User::where('user_id', 42)->first();`

Then reuse `$user` in the later code, then it will reuse it because you are using a variable.

But every time you make a call like `User::where('user_id', 42)->first();`, that does directly trigger a new database call.  So, the answer to your question is no, it won't 'reuse' it, unless you use a variable, and don't make the eloquent call the second time.

Since you're asking this question, there are a couple of other things you might be thinking of; one is caching, another is eager loading, which is a slightly different thing, to do with loading related models onto the actual model that makes up the call; yet another us Auth::user(), but that's not the example you've given above with User:: so I assume you didn't mean that.

Comment: Thank you, thats's exactly what I wanted to know! How does Auth::user() behave differently?

Comment: Glad to help.  AFAIK it should be possible for laravel to do the Auth::user() query only once per request, i.e. internally cache it, even if it's called multiple times (since the authenticated user cannot change during a single request..), but it's such a low impact query that I haven't actually ever tracked down whether laravel in fact does that or not. I wouldn't worry about it personally. The authors of the framework know what they are doing :)

Comment: Answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29566182/does-laravel-query-database-each-time-i-call-authuser